# two option button to return value to a specific cell in worksheet

Tags: vba

In my `Userform` I have two option buttons to identify the payment mode: 'cash' mode or 'cheque' mode.

If Cash mode is selected I need to return return a value "Cash" to worksheet3 ('Database') cell G, G+1, G+2 so on. If Cheque mode is selected it should return "Cheque in the same cell.

My other textBox, comboBox data is working fine and returning perfectly to the 'Database' Sheet from A to F.

Is there any code for commend Button to show the worksheet

Kindly Help.

Comment: Sure there is. Can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly setting the values in cells?

```
Dim i as integer
i = 1
With Worksheets("Database")
    For i = 1 to {number of rows here}
        .Cells(i,7) = "Cash"
    Next i
End with
```